# Why the ERR trap get triggerred in bash from "echo <(cat <<EOF"

Tags: bash

I have this script (test.sh) :

```
#!/bin/bash
  
set -o errtrace

trap 'echo $BASH_VERSION >&2' ERR

echo <(cat<<EOF
Hello world
EOF
)
```

Running it, I get :

```
~/tmp$ bash test.sh
/dev/fd/63
~/tmp$ 5.0.18(1)-release
```

Two questions :

1. Why ERR trap get triggerred ?
2. Why `5.0.18(1)-release` is after next prompt, not before it

Comment: Removed the WSL tag since this is portable behavior and can be expected to happen on all platforms where bash is supported.

Comment: BTW, this is a place where `errtrace` actually makes your code slower to execute: If there's nothing the shell would need to do after it finishes running `cat`, it'll implicitly `exec` the process, replacing the subshell created for the process substitution with a copy of `cat` instead of needing to start an _additional_ subprocess (as a child of the process substitution / grandchild of the original shell) to replace with the `/usr/bin/cat` binary. As soon as you have an action the shell needs to take _after_ `cat` is complete, that optimization is no longer available.

Comment: ...using `<(exec cat ...)` would override that, and also avoid your bug (as a shell that's no longer running can't run a trap).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your copy of `cat` exits with a nonzero exit status because it's not able to write its output to stdout (since nothing in your code running in the parent shell *actually reads from* `/dev/fd/63`). The subshell spawned to run that copy of `cat` thus registers an error. As `errtrace` causes your ERR handler to be used in subshells and other contexts, this thus causes the process substitution's subshell to invoke the handler.

Because this process substitution is running in a subshell, it's asynchronous from the rest of your script; and `cat` is only given an error after the `echo` has exited (since it's only at that time that the read end of the FIFO is closed, and thus cat's attempts to write result in a SIGPIPE).

Comment: And: If `errtrace` or `-E` is set, any trap on `ERR` is inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a sub‐shell environment. The `ERR` trap is normally not inherited in such cases. So normally the error within the sub-shell would not be trapped. Here it because of the `errtrace` option. If you add `echo $? >&2` inside the sub-shell, it will reveal the error code of 141.

Comment: Yup. Figured the OP knew that since they were going out of their way to use errtrace, but... not a bad idea to call it out; I'll edit appropriately.